# How can I send multiple variable to JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am having trouble to send multiple variables to my JSP.
Here is my action :

```
if(rcn != null) {
            infoRcn = ficheProduitService.getInfoCcn(rcn);  //Get informations from this rcn
            lCommentaireRcn = commentaireService.getCommentaries(rcn); //Get comments from this rcn
        } else {
            rcn = rcnForm.getRcnAlternate();
            infoRcn = ficheProduitService.getInfoCcn(rcn);
            lCommentaireRcn = commentaireService.getCommentaries(rcn);  public DtoFicheProduit getInfoRcn() {
    return infoRcn;
}

public void setInfoRcn(DtoFicheProduit infoRcn) {
    this.infoRcn = infoRcn;
}

public List<DtoCommentaire> getlCommentaireRcn() {
    return lCommentaireRcn;
}

public void setlCommentaireRcn(List<DtoCommentaire> lCommentaireRcn) {
    this.lCommentaireRcn = lCommentaireRcn;
}
```

lCommentaire is not empty I checked it with debugger. Here is my JSP :

```
<s:property value="%{lCommentaireRcn}" />
<s:property value="%{infoRcn.daoFicheProduit.essentialite}" />
```

I get infoRcn but not lCommentaireRcn.

Can you explain me what am I doing wrong please ?

Thanks

Comment: I would drop the `l` prefix: `commentaireRcn`, `getCommentaireRcn()`

Comment: Multiple values are displayed via iterator tag, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248546/573032

Comment: @JBNizet is correct.  It is the getter/setter names that are having the issue.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4778

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks !! I dropped the l prefix and it works !

Comment: @RomanC yes, I wanted to check first if my data has been sent correctly.

Comment: @Hiitch Sent where? The data is sent incorrectly.